# Asking boolean question on the nodes of a DAG to find the target node

Tags: graph-theory, directed-acyclic-graph, search-problem

We are given a DAG $G=(V, E)$ and an unknown target node $x \in V$ to find. There is a mechanism to probe a node, $y \in V$, to ask question of the form "*Given the node $y$, is the target node $x$ in the ancestors of $y$ (inclusive) or not?*". The objective of the problem is to find the minimum set of nodes to probe to find $x$.

Are there any similar problems in graph theory?